# PHP move_uploaded_file not working but no errors either?

Tags: php

I'm trying to move my uploaded file to a pictures folder. I dont get any errors when it comes to the script. Im using godaddy as the host. All file permissions are set up correctly. Have really no idea what else to do.

This is the php code:

```
<?php
public function CheckPicture($picture){

    if(empty($_FILES['picture']['name'])){
        echo "Must choose a file.";
    }else{
        $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
        $file_name = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
//line 157->$file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
        $file_temp = $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'];    
        if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed)){
            $this->UploadPicture($username, $file_name, $file_extn);
        }else{
            echo $file_extn;
            echo "Incorect file type. Types allowed: ";
            echo implode(', ' , $allowed);
        }
    }
}

public function UploadPicture($username, $file_temp, $file_extn){

    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);    
    $file_path = '/home/content/49/11554349/html/gb/dev/images/pictures/' . substr(md5(time()), 0 , 9) . '.' . $file_extn;
    move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
    echo $file_path;    
    print_r("$file_temp");
}
?>
```

This is how I am calling it in the html:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once('post.php');
$username = unserialize($_SESSION["username"]);
$email = $_SESSION["email"];
if(!$_SESSION["username"]){
    header("Location: http://www.greenboardapp.com/dev/");
}

if(isset($_FILES['picture'])){
    $upload = new Post();
    $upload->CheckPicture($picture);
}
?>
```

This is the form:

```
<div class="tile">
    <img src="images/profileimg.png" alt="Tutors" class="tile-image">
        <form action="profile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
            <label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="picture"><br>
            <h6><input type="submit" value="Change Profile Pic" class="btn btn-hg btn-success"></h6>
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the target directory writeable for PHP/Apache?

Comment: I didn't see the Post class define. Put     ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);  just before session_start(), so it will show all the errors

Comment: Put `die` after `header("Location` and turn on error reporting (`error_reporting(-1)`).

Comment: Suppose to be yes, had to call godaddy and make them verify for me that all the permissions where set up correctly

Comment: what is '$upload->CheckPicture($picture);' '$picture'?

Comment: both of those functions are inside the Post class. @ElonThan that (error_reporting(-1)) goes after the header?

Comment: @phpnoob It should be first line just after opening tag.

Comment: @ElonThan now im getting 2 errors Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/content/49/11554349/html/gb/dev/post.php on line 157 and Notice: Undefined variable: username in /home/content/49/11554349/html/gb/dev/post.php on line 160

Comment: marked the line of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that `end` requires a reference, because it modifies the internal representation of the array (it makes the current element pointer point to the last element).

The result of `explode('.', $file_name)` cannot be turned into a reference. This is a restriction in the PHP language, that probably exists for simplicity reasons.

### Output for 5.1.0 - 5.5.6

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference
```

### Output for 5.0.5

```
Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference
Process exited with code 255.
```

### Output for 4.3.0 - 5.0.4

```
Success
```

---

### Solution

Find:

```
        $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
        $file_temp = $picture['tmp_name'];
```

Change to:

```
        $file_extn_ex = explode('.', $file_name);
        $file_extn_end = end($file_extn_ex);
        $file_extn = strtolower($file_extn_end);
        $file_temp = $picture['tmp_name'];
```

Comment: Will not change anything. This parameter is not even used in method.

Comment: Please take a look again on the code @ElonThan. The function will receive `$_FILES['picture']` as `$picture` inside the function and use the contents of that. That's whats going wrong, the content of `$_FILES['picture']` never reaches the function as `$picture` is not set.

Comment: changed it, same thing though. i do have new errors that i posted on comments above and marked the line of the error

Comment: Of course it reaches function and can be used because `$_FILES` is superglobal just like `$_POST`. Check again and see that there is no `$picture` in method body (which have to be used to use that parameter).

Comment: Look at my answer again @ElonThan, the `Only variables should be passed by reference` error is coming from the `end` function.

Comment: @JoranDenHouting how come? or then what else can I use in that case

Comment: @JoranDenHouting sweet thanks that covered all the errors again but for some reason is still not moving the image to the directory that I want, must be a permissions thing?

Comment: @phpnoob, I think so.. Looking at your code I don't see anything special for moving the files.. Path is right? Permissions of the folder is set to `CHMOD 0777`?

Comment: @JoranDenHouting called godaddy and asked, guy said all the permissions are set correctly and the path is the right one so idk...

Comment: Did you check by yourself? Is the folder 777? Cuz I know GoDaddy and they told me many more "good" things.. Never trust on someone at the other side of the phone, only trust those people ate StackOverflow who actually will help you :p

Comment: thing is I dont know how to check, and I cant check from the file manager I use from godaddy anyways. All I can see is that the web user permissions are set to read, write and execute. And thanks for assistance been really helpful